# What is the difference between combinations with repetition and permutations with indistinguishable objects?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am wondering what is the difference between combinations with repetition and permutations with indistinguishable objects or if they are the same. I am asking because the problem below can be solved with both formulas 1 and 2. This confuses me a bit because order does not matter in the question but a permutation formula still gives the correct answer.

My understanding is that combinations with repetition is the number of selections that can be made when there are duplicate objects involved, whereas permutations with indistinguishable objects is the number of arrangements containing duplicate objects.

1. Combinations with repetition formula:
   $$C(n+r-1,r) = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$$
2. Modified permutations with indistinguishable objects ($n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$ formula:
   $$\frac{(n+r-1)!}{n_1!n_2!...n_k!}$$

---

**Question:** Five people go to a restaurant and can each order the following: cheeseburger (c), hot dog (h), taco (t) and sandwich (s). How many different purchases are there?

**Original answer:**

- n = 4, r = 5
  $$C(n+r-1,r) = \frac{(4+5-1)!}{5!(4-1)!} = \frac{8!}{5!3!} = 56$$
- diagram used to represent one possible purchase: $$x | x | x |xx$$ where the x's separated by bars in positions 1 to 4 represent c,h,t,ss respectively.

**Alternate answer using permutations with indistinguishable objects:**

- possible purchases: cchts, chtss, hhtss
- which correspond to $xx | x | x |x$, $x| x | x |xx$, $| xx | x |xx$
- see that these are arrangements of identical objects (8 total objects: 3 bars, 5 x's), so the answer is $$\frac{8!}{5!3!} = 56$$

Comment: You need to clarify for yourself for these problems what plays the roles of the "*objects*" being arranged.  The objects being arranged being the x's and |'s... sure... they're the same, just different rewordings of one another.  You will find that most problems in combinatorics can be thought of as rephrasings of one another... for instance [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) can be thought of as counting dyck words, lattice paths not crossing diagonal, rooted binary trees, and so on...

Comment: Now... as for an example where one makes sense to use but not the other...  "How many ways can the five people order food such that it matters who gets what type of food and there were specifically a total of two hotdogs, two tacos, and one sandwich ordered?"  That would have been $\frac{5!}{2!2!1!}$.  That is the type of question we usually intend when talking about permutations with repetition.

Comment: Yes but since this problem I posted is from a combinations with repetitions chapter, I am curious why using the permutations with indistinguishable objects formula gave the same correct answer. I think the reason why using the permutations formula gave the same answer is because arranging the x's and |'s corresponds to different selections of the foods. And then dividing by 5!3! removed x's and |'s from being arranged in the same permutation which corresponds to removing permutations such as cchts, htscc, sthcc, etc, which all are one combination. I'm still a bit confused about the difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is very beautiful answer for your question in Kenneth Rosens discrete math book.Assume that each bar is used to separate kinds and stars is used to denote how many number of element will be selected in that kinds .Look at : https://epdf.pub/discrete-mathematics-and-its-applications-5ea6d47f35e5f.html , page $411$. For example , the given example by you says that $2$ burger will be taken by first kind ,and the first segment represent cheeseburger . By using permutation with repetition ,we find all possible arrangement in such way . When we comes to your question , there is not difference between them to solve these kinds of combinatorics problems. It is generally taught permutation with repetiton to solve this problems by some teachers. However, Combination with repetiton formula is used to solve these problems by some teachers

Comment: This answer is confusing in some parts. Also you link to something that *looks* like it gives a pdf to Rosen's book but when one gets there it is a site where one has to jump through a bunch of hoops to go anywhere, not a simple link to the book pdf.

Comment: @coffeemath let me correct it

Comment: @coffeemath does the link work now ?

Comment: Yes link is more direct now. But still one needs to download a big file to read it. Not a big deal but would take some space, maybe I'll try it eventually.